# How to generate a list of all subtrees in Clojure using higher order functions?

Tags: clojure, tree

Given a tree, how do you generate a list of all (proper) subtrees in Clojure using higher order functions?

**Background**

I am working on *Advent of Code 2019* [Problem #6](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/6).  The problem begins with an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).  I have represented the adjacency list as an n-ary tree, using Clojure lists, with the following structure.

A node that is not a leaf is a list with two parts: the first part is an element representing the root of that section of the tree; the second part is a *n* elements representing branches from the root.  Leaves are lists having a keyword as their only element.  Thus, I represent a tree of the form,

```
  B -- C
 /
A
 \
  D
```

with the following list:

```
(:A (:B (:C)) (:D))
```

**Solution using Recursion**

I want to list every proper subtree of a given tree.  I know how to do this using recursion, as follows:

```
(defn subtrees
  [tree]
  (loop [trees tree
         results '()]
    (if (empty? trees)
      results
      (let [subtree #(if (keyword? (first %)) (rest %) nil)
            leaf? #(and (list %) (keyword? (first %)) (= (count %) 1))
            sub (subtree (first trees))]
        (if (every? leaf? sub)
          (recur (rest trees) (into results sub))
          (recur (into (rest trees) sub) (into results sub)))))))
```

So I do the work with `trees` and `results`: I begin with the tree in `trees`, and then add each subtree that is not one or more leaves into `trees` and `results` at each step (or: just into `results` if I have one or more leaves).  This gives me a list of all proper subtrees of `tree`, which is the point of the function.  [Here is the working solution](https://github.com/curiousyogurt/AdventOfCode2019/blob/master/src/advent2019/day6a.clj) with very detailed comments and a bunch of test cases.

**My Question**

I should like to know how to accomplish the same using higher-order functions.  What I would really like to do is use `map` and call the function recursively: at each stage, just call `subtree` on every element in the list.  The problem I have encountered is that when I do this, I end up with a huge mess of parentheses and can't consistently drill down through the mess to get to the subtrees.  Something like this:

```
(defn subt
  [trees]
  (let [subtree #(if (keyword? (first %)) (rest %) nil)
        leaf? #(and (list %) (keyword? (first %)) (= (count %) 1))
        sub (subtree trees)]
    (if (every? leaf? sub)
      nil
      (cons (map subt sub) trees))))
```

You can see the `(map subt sub)` is what I'm going for here, but I am running into a lot of difficulty using `map`, even though my sense is that is what I want for my higher-order function.  I thought about using `reduce` as a stand-in for the `loop` in `subtrees` above; but because `trees` changes by subtrees being added, I don't think `reduce` is appropriate, at least with the loop as I have constructed it.  **I should say, also, that I'm not interested in a library to do the work; I want to know how to solve it using core functions.**  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt at computing all the subtrees using various functions from the standard library.

```clj
(defn expand-subtrees [tree-set]
  (into #{} (comp (map rest) cat) tree-set))

(defn all-subtrees [tree]
  (reduce into #{}
          (take-while seq (iterate expand-subtrees #{tree}))))
```

and we can call it like this:

```clj
(all-subtrees '(:A (:B (:C)) (:D)))
;; => #{(:D) (:B (:C)) (:C) (:A (:B (:C)) (:D))}
```

The helper function `expand-subtrees` takes a set of trees and produces a new set of first-level subtrees of the input set. Then we use [iterate](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) with `expand-subtrees`, starting with the initial tree, to produce a sequence of expanded subtrees. We take elements from this sequence until there are no more subtrees. Then we merge all subtrees into a set, which is the result. Of course, you can [disj](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/disj) the initial tree from that set if you desire.

Comment: A follow-up question: is it idiomatic in Clojure to keep the helper function `expand-subtrees` separate?  Or would it be more common to make it part of the `all-subtrees` function?

Comment: notice, that this solution only collects *unique* subtrees. Though it still works for the task's input, doesn't really get `all-subtrees` as it's name states.

Comment: also, `(complement empty?)` is just `seq`. The documentation says "Please use the idiom (seq x) rather than (not (empty? x))"

Comment: @CuriousYogurt I think it is more readable as a separate function because (i) it is obvious that it computes its result from only one value and nothing captured from the surrounding scope and (ii) it makes `all-subtrees` more readable with less clutter. @leetwinski If two subtrees map to the same set element, it means they are *equal values*. So we will be collecting *all* subtrees, just that some subtrees can exist in many places of the tree. You could trivially replace `#{}` by `[]` to collect the subtrees from a breadth-first traversal if you so desire.

Answer (score 1):

i may be mistaken, but seems like the `tree-seq` function from the core lib should do the trick for you:

```
(tree-seq seq rest '(:A (:B (:C)) (:D)))

;;=> ((:A (:B (:C)) (:D)) (:B (:C)) (:C) (:D))
```

you just have to exclude the first item, being the tree itself.

I know, that is not the answer to "how to write this code manually",
but analyzing the `tree-seq` source code should clarify how to do it idiomatically in clojure.

in fact it uses something like this (simplified):

```
(defn my-tree-seq [data]
  (lazy-seq (cons data (mapcat my-tree-seq (rest data)))))
```

this one is lazy, so it doesn't lead to stack overflow despite the usage of recursion. I don't really think if should be optimized any more, but for the sake of education.

what about the task itself, i would simplify it somehow, since you don't really need subtrees, rather you only need every item's parents count. So you don't even need to build tree, just the child->parent lookup table. I can think of something like this:

```
(defn solve [data]
  (let [items (clojure.string/split data #"\)|\s+")
        pairs (partition 2 items)
        lookup (reduce (fn [acc [par ch]] (assoc acc ch par)) {} pairs)
        count-parents #(->> %
                            (iterate lookup)
                            (take-while identity)
                            count
                            dec)]
    (apply + (map count-parents (distinct items)))))

(def data "COM)B
           B)C
           C)D
           D)E
           E)F
           B)G
           G)H
           D)I
           E)J
           J)K
           K)L")

#'user/data

user> (solve data)
;;=> 42

user> (solve (slurp "./orb.txt"))
;;=> 402879 ;; for my task input data
```

this one could be further optimized with dynamic programming, but for provided inputs it is good enough.

Comment: The `tree-seq` does what I am looking for; thank you.  And you are right—it is from the core library.  But, as you intuit, I am looking for how to do it manually.  It's not that I do not appreciate your answer; it does fit with my question.  But Rulle's answer more closely fits what I was looking for in terms of a "manual" approach.

Comment: @CuriousYogurt thanks for the feedback! Also `my-tree-seq` is the most idiomatic clojure I can even think of. (That's why the core lib uses this exact approach) ))

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a solution similar in spirit to Rulle's but improving on it:

```
(def subtrees-bf
  (comp
    (partial apply concat)
    (partial take-while seq)
    (partial iterate (partial mapcat rest))
    rest)) ; replace this with list to include the original tree
```

Notice that the subtrees are produced lazily and in breadth-first order. To produce them in depth-first order (as in leetwinski's solution but using `iterate` and avoiding recursion) we can write:

```
(def subtrees-df
  (comp
    (partial map first)
    (partial take-while seq)
    (partial iterate
      (comp
        (partial apply concat)
        (juxt (comp rest first) rest)))
    rest)) ; replace this with list to include the original tree
```

I wrote these functions in the point-free style, which Clojure (like most LISP's) doesn't facilitate, some of the main causes being:

- many-argument functions instead of one-sequential-argument ones
- uncurried functions
- lack of many higher-order functions that constitute basic components of the algebra of point-free functional programming (as seen in the work of Richard Bird, Lambert Meertens and their circle - [this paper](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf) is a concise source of relevant information)

Two more idiomatic/comprehensible versions could be:

```
(defn subtrees-bf [tree]
  (->> tree
       rest ; or list
       (iterate (partial mapcat rest))
       (take-while seq)
       (apply concat)))

(defn subtrees-df [tree]
  (->> tree
       rest ; or list
       (iterate #(concat (rest (first %)) (rest %)))
       (take-while seq)
       (map first)))
```

And now let's generalize these approaches and rewrite `tree-seq`:

```
(defn tree-seq-bf [branch? children node]
  (let [children #(if (branch? %) (children %))]
    (->> node
         list
         (iterate (partial mapcat children))
         (take-while seq)
         (apply concat))))

(defn tree-seq-df [branch? children node]
  (let [children #(if (branch? %) (children %))]
    (->> node
         list
         (iterate #(concat (children (first %)) (rest %)))
         (take-while seq)
         (map first))))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish with the function `walk-with-parents-readonly` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  Here is the code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]))

(def orbits
  [:com
   [:b
    [:g
     [:h]]
    [:c
     [:d
      [:i]
      [:e
       [:f]
       [:j
        [:k
         [:l]]]]]]]])

(def sum (atom 0))

(defn parent-levels
  [parents]
  (t/it-> parents
    (count it)
    (/ it 2)))

(defn count-orbits
  [data]
  (t/walk-with-parents-readonly data
    {:enter (fn [parents item]
              (when (vector? item)
                (let [levels (parent-levels parents)]
                  (t/spyx [(first item) levels])
                  (swap! sum + levels))))}))

(dotest
  (count-orbits orbits)
  (t/spyx @sum))
```

with result

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 14
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
[(first item) levels] => [:com 0]
[(first item) levels] => [:b 1]
[(first item) levels] => [:g 2]
[(first item) levels] => [:h 3]
[(first item) levels] => [:c 2]
[(first item) levels] => [:d 3]
[(first item) levels] => [:i 4]
[(first item) levels] => [:e 4]
[(first item) levels] => [:f 5]
[(first item) levels] => [:j 5]
[(first item) levels] => [:k 6]
[(first item) levels] => [:l 7]
(clojure.core/deref sum) => 42
```

You can [see the docs here](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.core#walk-with-parents).   The source code [shows how to implement it](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/cljc/tupelo/core.cljc#L2923) (could be simplified for a specific use-case).

Comment: Thank you; I really appreciate it.  I'm specifically looking to do this without additional libraries, but rather using the core functions.  (That requirement is on the last line of the original question; I should have found a way to highlight it.)

Comment: See the source code (link added above). The basic idea is that upon every recursion, you append the `parents` vector with the current element.  Then you count the length of the parents vec and sum them up to get the total.

Comment: Thank you.  I get the basic idea; but this is using `forv` in the source.  What I would like to know is the details of how to do it using a higher order function.

Comment: `map` and `for` both apply a function to every item in a collection.  You can easily substitute one for the other.  I think `for` is easier to read in most instances, since it is more spread out, with the function at the end instead of the middle of the form.  Also, `for` gives an explicit name to the loop variable, where `map` normally doesn't.

Comment: Yes; I mean, I know how to use `map` and `for`.  The basic ideas isn't hard.  The problem I'm having is dealing with the huge number of parentheses that drown out the result when I use higher-order functions.  There seem to be too many individual cases that have slightly different formats in the results.

Comment: Don't try to do it in a single highly-nested expression.  Make a bunch of short helper functions so it never gets more than 2 levels of nesting.